# Javascript optimizing the repetitive JSON object to output below

Tags: javascript

So I have an array of objects coming from database like,

```
[
{
  id:1,
  group:x,
  a_flag:1,
  a_value:50  
}
,
{
  id:1,
  group:x,
  a_flag:2,
  a_value:100,
},
{
  id:1,
  group:x,
  a_flag:0,
  a_value:200
},
{
 id:1,
 group:y,
 ....
 ....
}
{
  id:2,
  group:x,
  a_flag:1,
  a_value:100
},
...
]
```

The operation that I want to perform is, group by the group present and make it as a single id, with some computations based on flag and value. In essence, if the `a_flag` = 1 or 2, divide the `a_value` of it by the `a_value` where `a_flag` = 0.

So my desired output is:

```
[
{
  id:1,
  group_1_flag:[{"key":"x","value":0.25 (i.e 50/200)},{"key":"y","value":0.5(same logic)}]
  group_2_flag:[{"key":"x","value":0.75 (i.e 150/200)},{"key":"y","value":0.7 (same logic)}]
}
]
```

What I have tried:

I used `_.groupBy` method to group by groups present. But I couldn't figure out the logic behind merging the repeating id's to a single id with all the computations above.

Thanks!

Comment: does the data match the wanted output? what happens to `id: 2`? where do you get `150` from?

Comment: Yes, it is similar to id:1. I will be getting those from a_value = 150 where a_flag = 1 and a_value = 200 where a_flag = 0. And dividing those two. Similar to the process of id:1

Answer (score 0):

You could group first and then map the wanted values.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, group: 'x', a_flag: 1, a_value: 50 }, { id: 1, group: 'x', a_flag: 2, a_value: 100 }, { id: 1, group: 'x', a_flag: 0, a_value: 200 }, { id: 1, group: 'y', a_flag: 1, a_value: 50 }, { id: 1, group: 'y', a_flag: 2, a_value: 140 }, { id: 1, group: 'y', a_flag: 0, a_value: 200 }, { id: 2, group: 'x', a_flag: 1, a_value: 100 }, { id: 2, group: 'x', a_flag: 2, a_value: 200 }, { id: 2, group: 'x', a_flag: 0, a_value: 50 }],
    result = Object
        .values(data.reduce((r, { id, group, a_flag, a_value }) => {
            r[id] = r[id] || { id, flags: {} };
            r[id].flags[a_flag] = r[id].flags[a_flag] || { };
            r[id].flags[a_flag][group] = a_value;
            return r;
        }, {}))
        .map(({ id, flags }) => Object.assign(
            { id },
             ...[1, 2].map(k =>
                 k in flags && { [`group_${k}_flag`]: Object.entries(flags[k]).map(([key, v]) => 
                     ({ key, value: v / flags[0][key] })) })
        ));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please explain the code as I am a newbie.